# Issue with copying text in php and javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am creating a table that is being displayed with data from a mysql database.  I am attempting to make an option to copy information from the diplayed table to the clipboard.  I am using a loop to create the rows on the table since the number of rows can and will vary.

The problem is that the copy button only copies the info from the last row regardless of which row the button is clicked from.

I have used the common javascript method to copy the data to the clipboard.  I'm passing along the id for the input from php into javascript via a variable.

I understand the reason is that the variable is changed to the last row each time the loop completes.  I am not terribly famalier with javascript so I'm sure there is an easy fix for the issue and I'm probably overthinking it.  I am aware that I do not need to have the script in the loop, I was just playing with a couple different ways to see if I could get it to work.  Please dont judge too harshly on the code, I'm just trying to get it to work before I make anything final.

```
if (mysqli_num_rows($result)> 0) { while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) { $rowtocopy = 'Row' . $row['Row']; ?>
<script>
  function copytoclipboard() {
    /* Get the text field */
    var coord_id = '<?=$rowtocopy?>';
    var copyText = document.getElementById(coord_id);

    /* Select the text field */
    copyText.select();
    copyText.setSelectionRange(0, 99999); /* For mobile devices */

    /* Copy the text inside the text field */
    navigator.clipboard.writeText(copyText.value);

    /* Alert the copied text */
    alert("Coordinates copied to clipboard: " + copyText.value);
  }
</script>
<?php
            echo 
            '<tr>
                <td align="center">' . $row["Row"] . '<input type="text" value="' . $row['Row'] . '" id="Row' . $row['Row'] . '" hidden="true" /><img src="clipboard.png" height="20px" onclick="copytoclipboard()" /></td>
            </tr>';
            }
            }else{
            echo "there was a problem<br />";
            }
        ?>
```

Comment: pass a unique id to `coord_id` please

Comment: I have tried this already and the problem is the coord_id variable changes each time the loop runs.  so the variable still ends up being the coord_id on the last row.    for example, I have changed the coord_id to Row1 (and had it auto increment on each loop) So on the last row its Row3.  any time i click the copy button, it only copies the data from Row3.  I can manually code all the rows, but that will be a bit of a pain if there are more than 5-10 rows.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is rooted in (as you mentioned) each time you loop, it overwrites the `copytoclipboard()` function and specifically sets:

```
var coord_id = '<?=$rowtocopy?>';
```

Therefore, whenever ANY onClick handler calls `copytoclipboard()`, it's going to see the last time `coord_id` was set as that was the last time the function was defined, resulting in always copying the last row.

To fix this:

1. Move the function out of the loop.
2. Pass in the coord_id as a parameter

Something conceptually like this (not tested):

```
<script>
function copytoclipboard(coord_id) {
   ...
}
</script>

<?php
foreach($rows as $row) {
   echo "<tr><td><a href='#' onClick='copytoclipboard('Row" + $row['Row'] + "')'>Copy</a></td></tr>"
}
```

Comment: I tried it didnt work.  I was able to get a unique id for each of them.  Everything rendered correctly looking at the source code.  I'm going to come back to this at a later time.  Thanks for the help.